# Cannot receive contentType "application/pdf" using RestResponse

Tags: rest, delphi, pdf, client

My application sends data(personal info) using "application/json". If data is valid, then, server sends me back a PDF File through "application/pdf". But when RestResponse arrives, an exception pops out: "No mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page". I don't know whats happening. I'm working on this in the past 4 days and I can't fix this. Exception pops out at line: "RRequest.Execute;". Here's my code guys:

```
procedure TThreadBoleto.Execute;
var
  RCtx : TRttiContext;
  RType : TRttiType;
  RProp : TRttiProperty;
  I : integer;
  PDF : TFile;
begin
  try
    try
      RClient := TRESTClient.Create('');
      with RClient do begin
        AcceptEncoding := 'identity';
        FallbackCharsetEncoding := 'UTF-8';
        Accept := 'application/json;text/plain;application/pdf;';
        AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
        BaseURL := 'https://sandbox.boletocloud.com/api/v1/boletos';
        ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        HandleRedirects := true;

        RCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
        RType := RCtx.GetType(THRBoleto.ClassType);
        I := 0;
        for RProp in RType.GetProperties do
        begin
          Params.AddItem;
          Params.Items[I].name := LowerCase(RProp.Name.Replace('_','.'));
          Params.Items[I].Value := RProp.GetValue(THRBoleto).AsString;
          I := I + 1;
        end;
      end;

      RRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(RRequest);
      with RRequest do begin
        Accept := 'application/json;text/plain;application/pdf;';
        Client := RClient;
        Method := rmPost;
        SynchronizedEvents := false;
        AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
      end;

      RResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(RResponse);
      RResponse.ContentType := 'application/pdf;*/*;';
      RResponse.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';

      RAuth := THTTPBasicAuthenticator.Create('','');
      with RAuth do begin
        Username := 'anAPItokenAccess';
        Password := 'token';
      end;

      RClient.Authenticator := RAuth;
      RRequest.Response := RResponse;

      RRequest.Execute;
      PDF.WriteAllBytes(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'boleto.pdf',RResponse.RawBytes);
      OutputStrings.Add(RResponse.Content);
      OutputStrings.Add('');
      OutputStrings.Add('');
      OutputStrings.AddStrings(RResponse.Headers);
    except on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: '+E.Message);
    end;
  finally
  THRBoleto.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the error is happening on the `RRequest.Execute()` call? You are trying to receive the PDF data as a `String` when you read the `RResponse.Content` property, so I would expect a Unicode error on that call instead.  A PDF file is not textual data, it is binary data, so the only safe way to receive it is with the `RResponse.RawBytes` property.

Also, you should not be setting the `RResponse.ContentType` or `RResponse.ContentEncoding` properties at all (not to mention that you are setting them to invalid values anyway).  They will be filled in according to the actual response that is received.

Since you are setting the `RRequest.Accept` property to include 3 different media types that you are willing to accept in a response, you need to look at the `RResponse.ContentType` property value to make sure you are actually receiving a PDF file before saving the `RawBytes` to a `.pdf` file.  If you receive a text or JSON response instead, you can't process them as a PDF.

Personally, I find the REST components to be quite buggy.  You might have better luck using Indy's `TIdHTTP` instead, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal, IdGlobalProtocols, IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

procedure TThreadBoleto.Execute;
var
  RCtx : TRttiContext;
  RType : TRttiType;
  RProp : TRttiProperty;
  Client: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TStringList;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Client := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    with Client.Request do begin
      AcceptEncoding := 'identity';
      Accept := 'application/json;text/plain;application/pdf';
      AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
      ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      BasicAuthentication := True;
      Username := 'anAPItokenAccess';
      Password := 'token';
    end;
    Client.HandleRedirects := true;

    RCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
    RType := RCtx.GetType(THRBoleto.ClassType);

    Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Params := TStringList.Create;
      try
        for RProp in RType.GetProperties do
          Params.Add(LowerCase(RProp.Name.Replace('_','.')) + '=' + RProp.GetValue(THRBoleto).AsString);

        Client.Post('https://sandbox.boletocloud.com/api/v1/boletos', Params, Response);
      finally
        Params.Free;
      end;

      Response.Position := 0;
      case PosInStrArray(ExtractHeaderMediaType(Client.Response.ContentType), ['application/pdf', 'application/json', 'text/plain'], False) of
        0: begin
          // save PDF
          Response.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'boleto.pdf');
          OutputStrings.Add('[PDF file]');
        end;
        1: begin
          // process JSON as needed
          OutputStrings.Add(ReadStringAsCharset(Response, Client.Response.Charset));
        end;
        2: begin
          // process Text as needed
          OutputStrings.Add(ReadStringAsCharset(Response, Client.Response.Charset));
        end;
      else
        // something else!
        OutputStrings.Add('[Unexpected!]');
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;

    OutputStrings.Add('');
    OutputStrings.Add('');
    OutputStrings.AddStrings(Client.Response.RawHeaders);
  finally
    Client.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadBoleto.DoTerminate;
begin
  if FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    // Note: ShowMessage() is NOT thread-safe!
    ShowMessage('Error: ' + Exception(FatalException).Message);
  end;
  THRBoleto.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: I'm testing...but it gives me an error: "Could not load SSL library". DLL files exists in System and SysWow64, also at EXE's folder.

Comment: Are they up-to-date DLLs? What version of OpenSSL? What does Indy's `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad()` function say after the failure happens?

Comment: This is my response: 
`[Unexpected!]
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2016 18:37:46 GMT
Server: WildFly/10
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
X-BoletoCloud-Version: 0.9.32
Location: /api/v1/boletos/o13YvKcea3TyZidY1zblATvLCGLni0Yj0puZ48K7uWU=
X-BoletoCloud-NIB-Nosso-Numero: 000000000039-6
X-BoletoCloud-Token: o13YvKcea3TyZidY1zblATvLCGLni0Yj0puZ48K7uWU=
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ms-TGShZOYOL4tgoMuwfcXetu5jZtemrQQjpSb2o.sandbox-boletocloud.rhcloud.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: GEAR=local-57806f5d2d5271ac0a000009; path=/
Connection: close`

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting `[Unexpected!]`. The `Content-Type` clearly shows `application/pdf`, which is the very first case tested for. `ExtractHeaderMediaType(Client.Response.ContentType)` should be returning `application/pdf` with `charset` stripped off (which actually should have already been stripped off when `Content-Type` was parsed into `Client.Response.ContentType` and `Client.Response.Charset`) and `PosInStrArray()` should then be returning 0, not -1.

Comment: Thanks for your support, Remy Lebeau. Don't worry about `[Unexpected!]`, I can handle now.